# prevent running multiple instanes of a macro

Tags: vba

"how to avoid Running Multiple instances of macro"

```
Sub CallBot()
    If Activesheet.Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
        Call Bot
    ElseIf Activesheet.Range("B1").Value = 1 Then 
        Call BotTwo
    End If
    Application OnTime + TimeValue("00:01:00")
End Sub
```

This leads to multiple instances of CallBot Running(looping), but i want to run it every one minute only, pls help

Also tried following code

```
Sub CallBot()
    Dim TimeToRun
    If Activesheet.Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
        Call Bot
    ElseIf Activesheet.Range("B1").Value = 1 Then 
        Call BotTwo
    End If
    Application OnTime + TimeValue("00:01:00")
End Sub

Sub Repeat()
    If TimeToRun > 0 Then
        Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CallBot", False
    End If

    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:20")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CallBot"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set a global variable that keeps track of whether the bot is scheduled to run:

```
Public botScheduled As Boolean

Sub CallBot()
    If not botScheduled Then
        If Activesheet.Range("A1").Value = 1 Then
            Call Bot
            botScheduled = True
        ElseIf Activesheet.Range("B1").Value = 1 Then 
            Call BotTwo
            botScheduled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You haven't provided your `Bot` code, but when your bot code finishes, that's where you can set `botScheduled = False`.

Comment: i so sorry , its not Bot running multiple times its CallBot that keeps looping in multiple instances, so 'bot' is called multiple times!